# Matlab: track all file handles that were opened/touched by script

Tags: matlab

I want to find all dependencies of my script (and/or all subfunctions/subscripts), but *not only functions* that are called but also **external files that are loaded or touched (fopen)**. `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts` (documentation [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html)) doesn't capture the touched filenames, my next idea, shadow the fopen function using something like below (to copy the filename to a log file), resulted in an unexpected recursive loop.

failed because of (unexpected) recursive loop, where somehow the 'builtin' fopen is not called, rather this function itself:

```
function varargout=fopen(varargin)
  %write opened filename to log file somewhere
  varargout=builtin('fopen',varargin{:}); %attempt to call built-in fopen() as usual
end
```

I also checked Mathworks depencey reports etc, to no use. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Interesting problem. A really naive solution might be to read all your .m files related to your project and look for the lines that contain`fopen(` inside of them. Then it's just a matter of formatting those lines. This would, on the other hand, have problems with for loops, if conditions etc...

Comment: I found a way to modify the code above by removing the folder of the custom fopen wrapper script from path before calling the built-in function, then adding it again after. It's cumbersome and silly, but it works...